# Double indirection in C++ vtables

Tags: c++, pointers, assembly, function-pointers, vtable

I wrote this very simple C++ program, and I was wondering about why the compiler lays out the vtable across two pointer dereferences. Here's the C++ program:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  virtual void bar() {
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *arv[]) {
  Foo foo;
  Foo *foo_p(&foo);
  foo_p->bar();
}
```

Now, I can look at the compiler-generated assembly:

```
$ g++ -ggdb -Wall -O0 -S test.cpp
```

Here are the relevant sections:

```
    .loc 1 9 0 
    leaq    -16(%rbp), %rax  # put the address of 'foo' in %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi       # use it as the first argument of the following function
    call    _ZN3FooC1Ev      # call the Foo constructor
    .loc 1 10 0
    leaq    -16(%rbp), %rax  # put the address of 'foo' in %rax
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)  # create 'foo_p' on the stack
    .loc 1 11 0
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax  # load 'foo_p' into %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rax     # dereference the pointer, put it in %rax
                             # %rax now holds the hidden pointer in 'foo', which is the vtable pointer
    movq    (%rax), %rdx     # dereference the pointer ::again:: (with an offset of 0), put it in %rdx
                             # %rdx now holds a function pointer from the vtable
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax  # create the 'this' pointer (== foo_p) and put it in %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi       # use the 'this' pointer as the first argument to the following function
    call    *%rdx            # call Foo::bar (via the vtable)
```

Why the second pointer dereference is necessary? Why doesn't the 'hidden' vtable pointer in the object point directly into the vtable?

edit: It ::is:: pointing directly to the vtable. I just got confused with my pointers :-P

Comment: +1 There are no dumb questions if they are prepared like this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
movq    -24(%rbp), %rax  # load 'foo_p' into %rax
movq    (%rax), %rax     # fetch VTABLE
movq    (%rax), %rdx     # fetch function `bar` from VTABLE.
```

You'd see it better if you added a `baz` (or `kerflunk`) function as a second function to your class, you'd see the second fetch be at `8` into the VTABLE.

You can see the structure inside the class as something like this (note this is "for illustration purposes, not intended to be reality")

```
struct VTABLE
{
    void (*bar)();
};

struct Foo
{
    VTABLE *vtable;
};
```

Inside the constructor for Foo [which exists even though you haven't declared one], there is a piece of code that does:

```
this->vtable = &VTABLE_Foo;
```

and somewhere the compiler has done (again, for illustration purposes, the names are certainly different):

```
VTABLE VTABLE_Foo = { foo::bar };
```

So to call `bar`, we would do:

```
foo_p->vtable->bar(foo_p);
```

What the compiler shows is:

```
void (*temp)() = foo_p->vtable->bar;
temp(foo_p);
```

This is almost certainly a consequence of using `-O0`, and if you compile with optimization, the compiler will do it more straight forward (including possibly realizing it doesn't need a vtable in this case and inline the function which doesn't do anything, thus eliminate the call completely).

Comment: It's good to understand how this works, as long as you don't take it for granted this is EXACTLY how it ALWAYS works, as the compiler is allowed to do this "any way that actually gives the correct behaviour".

Answer (score 2):

The first puts the *vtable* pointer into `%rax`, and the second puts the *function* pointer into `%rdx`.